# python 3 unable to scrape

Tags: python

I am trying to translate Indonesian language to English using Google translate.(because I play a game that has a lot of Indonesians)

```
lang = id
inp = input("Enter to translate: \n").replace(" ","%20")

htmlfile = Request("https://translate.google.co.in/#" + lang + "/en/" + inp, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})  
htmltext = urlopen(htmlfile).read().decode('utf-8')
regex = '<span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="en">(.+?)</span>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
trans = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
print(trans)
```

when I give the input I get `[]`. Here is the inspect element

```
<span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="en">

 <span class="hps">

    greeting

 </span>
```

I need to get that "greeting" part

Answer (score 0):

It's not the problem with `urllib`, problem is mainly because of your regex. By default `.` in your regex would match any character but not of newline or carriage return characters. You need to enable DOTALL mode `(?s)` to make `.` to match even newline characters also.

```
regex = r'(?s)<span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="en">(.+?)</span>'
```

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """<span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="en">
... 
...  <span class="hps">
... 
...     greeting
... 
...  </span>"""
>>> re.findall(r'(?s)<span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="en">(.+?)</span>', s)
['\n\n <span class="hps">\n\n    greeting\n\n ']
>>> re.findall(r'(?s)<span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="en">(?:(?!</).)*?(\w+)\s*</span>', s)
['greeting']
```

Answer (score 0):

### Caveats:

First off, I would advise you read [the famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) to the question about how to parse HTML with regular expresssions. **TL;DR**: Don't do it. Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead.

That said, I'm not a lawyer, but what you are trying to do might be in violation of [Google's Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/intl/en-US/policies/terms/). They have a  [paid API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs), charging 20 USD per 1M characters of text (as of 26/Oct/2014), which might better suit your needs. Using the API has the additional benefit of protecting you from changes to the markup used that could otherwise break your code.

### If you do want to pursue this path:

Your regular expression is not matching newlines. You need to specify the [`DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag when you compile your regular expression. Your updated code could be:

```
lang = "id"
inp = input("Enter text to translate:\n").replace(" ","%20")

htmlfile = Request("https://translate.google.co.in/#" + lang + "/en/" + inp, 
                   headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})  
htmltext = urlopen(htmlfile).read().decode('utf-8')
pattern = re.compile(, )
trans = re.findall(
    '<span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="en">\\s+<span class="hps">(.+?)</span>',
    htmltext,
    re.DOTALL)
print(trans)
```

*Note that the regular expression adds `<span class="hps">` to exclude that from your matching text.*